# NestJs Get Execution Context in Pipes?

Tags: nestjs

I'm using Nestjs and am using a custom global Pipe to validate the body of the request. I need to pass in extra information to the pipe and was hoping I could use `SetMetadata` from `@nestjs/common` to add metadata for the pipe to use.

Although when trying to retrieve the metadata via `Reflector` class, it needs the `ExecutionContext`. e.g.

```
export const CustomValidatorOptions = (options: {}) => SetMetadata('customValidatorOptions', options);


export class CustomValidationPipe implements PipeTransform {

constructor(
    private reflector: Reflector,
) {}

  transform(value: any, metadata: ArgumentMetadata) {
      // context: ExecutionContext -> (How to get 2nd argument?)
      const metadata = this.reflector.get('customValidatorOptions', context.getHandler());
       
  }

}

class MyController {
   
   @Put(':id')
   @CustomValidatorOptions({ canPassThisToCustomValidatorPipe: true })
   myPut(@Body(): cat: CatDto) {}
}
```

Normally `ExecutionContext` will be provided as arguments of a route guard (e.g.   `canActivate(context: ExecutionContext) {}` Although how can I access `ExecutionContext` through a pipe?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to do with pipes. You could do something similar with an interceptor instead though. Just make sure to call the methods before `return next.handle()` if you go with that route.

Answer (score 0):

I could solve that by making a guard to change the request and add a typeORM entity depending on some specific decorator.

MY problem:
I want to pass a typeORM entity from the controller to the Pipe dynamically. The pipe would be used all over the application for multiple request, to validate. I want to have a decorator on the controller that will get the Entity I am referring it too and use it

For that I am adding a decorator on my controller:

```
@DynamicPipeForId(Restaurant)
export class RestaurantController extends JsonBaseController<Restaurant> {
```

The process will be:

- Make a Decorator / Metadata will be passed within the request object
- Make a Guard to get the metadata and bind the desired object (In my case typeORM entity) to the request object.
- Access the request object from the pipe and find the metadata you had previously set.

My Decorator to pass the metadata. Here I am passing a typeORM entity.

```
export const TargetEntityPipeId = (entity: Entity): CustomDecorator => SetMetadata(TARGET_ENTITY_PIPE_ID_KEY, entity);
```

Guard:
I don't want to make any checks. I just want to have some decorators I can add anywhere and they will be responsible for setting the meta on the request. In this case I am showing I am only setting one value, but I use the same guard to set multiple values to be available on the request object.

```
@Injectable()
export class DynamicGuard implements CanActivate {
    constructor(private reflector: Reflector) {}

    canActivate(context: ExecutionContext): boolean | Promise<boolean> | Observable<boolean> {
        const request = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();
        const entity = this.reflector.getAllAndOverride(TARGET_ENTITY_PIPE_ID_KEY, [
            context.getHandler(),
            context.getClass(),
        ]);
        request[TARGET_ENTITY_PIPE_ID_KEY] = entity;
        return true; // I don't make any checks
    }
}
```

PIPE:
As you can see here, I am getting the request and collecting the `user` that I have set in the jwt guard. But what you should pay attention in the `entityClass` that I am able to access as well.

```
@Injectable()
export class IdCheckPipe implements PipeTransform {
    constructor(
        @Inject(REQUEST) private readonly request: Request,
        @InjectDataSource() private readonly connection: Connection,
    ) {}

    async transform(value: any) {
        const user: ActiveUserData = await this.request[REQUEST_USER_KEY];
        const entityClass = await this.request[TARGET_ENTITY_PIPE_ID_KEY];
        try {
            await securityModifier(entityClass)?.canAccessId(user, value, this.connection);
        } catch (e) {
            throw new NotFoundException(`Not found id = ${value}`);
        }
        return value;
    }
}
```